# SSH Remote command exit code always get 0

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, exit-code

I found a strange error when I try to get SSH Remote command exit code.
I don't understand why it will get different result and how to explain it.
Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong or a better way to capture the exit status of the remote ssh command. Appreciate any help.

local command:

`ssh_test/test.sh; echo $?;`

`+ exit 1
1`

ssh command:(Ubuntu 18.04)

`ssh 127.0.0.1 "ssh_test/test.sh; echo $?"`

`+ exit 1
0`

test.sh

`#!/bin/bash
set -x
exit 1`

Comment: Just a guess, try without the  `-e`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should use single quotation marks to double quotation marks.
echo $? will become "0", if I use double quotation marks to execution ssh command.

`ssh 127.0.0.1 'ssh_test/test.sh; echo $?'`

Answer (score 1):

0 is the exit code being returned from the `echo` command. If you assign the exit code to a variable this can stop it from being masked with the result of `echo`.

Comment: I have got exit code by "echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]}")" , but the result is different with run the command in remote SSH environment.

Comment: I have do another testing to reproduce the error, the result is still different event I don't use echo command.